# Separate columns by their strings if they are different

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame, and I want to spli their columns if they contain different strings or words.

I am tryng different methods in R and it is not working

My data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "TAP1", "TAP1", "TAP2"), y = c("TAP1", "TAP2", "TAP2", "TAP3" ))
```

And, for example, I am trying with the first column this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "TAP1", "TAP1", "TAP2"))
df %>% separate(x, c("TAP1", "TAP2"), extra = "drop", fill = "right")
```

but is not working

I am having the next output:

```
TAP1 TAP2
1 <NA> <NA>
2 TAP1 <NA>
3 TAP1 <NA>
4 TAP2 <NA>
```

My expected output is:

```
 TAP1 TAP2
1 <NA> <NA>
2 TAP1 <NA>
3 TAP1 <NA>
4 <NA> TAP2
```

And I would like to do the same for all columns in the complete data frame where I have different combinations of words like TAP1, TAP2, TAP3 ... etc.

In this example, the final table taking in to account column x and y would be.

```
 df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "TAP1", "TAP1", "TAP2"), y = c("TAP1", "TAP2",   "TAP2", "TAP3" ))

  TAP1 TAP2 TAP1.1 TAP2.2 TAP3.3
1 <NA> <NA> TAP1   <NA>   <NA>
2 TAP1 <NA> <NA>   TAP2   <NA>
3 TAP1 <NA> <NA>   TAP2   <NA>
4 <NA> TAP2 <NA>   <NA>   TAP3
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the first dataset

Comment: My expcted output is showed at the buttom, with a column for each string. TAP1 in the first column and TAP2 in the second one.  For colum "y", I would like 3 columns, one for TAP1, another for TAP2 and another for TAP3.

Comment: What is the new input table

Comment: Thank you, I added the data frame above the final expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number(), y = x) %>%
   spread(y, x) %>% 
   select(TAP1, TAP2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  TAP1  TAP2 
#  <fct> <fct>
#1 <NA>  <NA> 
#2 TAP1  <NA> 
#3 TAP1  <NA> 
#4 <NA>  TAP2
```

---

With multiple columns, we can `gather` and `spread`

```
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>%
   gather(key, val, -rn) %>%
   mutate(val1 = val) %>% 
   unite(val, val,key) %>% 
   group_by(val) %>%    # not really need for this example
   mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% # not needed here though
   spread(val, val1) %>%
   select(starts_with("TAP"))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# TAP1_x TAP1_y TAP2_x TAP2_y TAP3_y
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 <NA>   TAP1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#2 TAP1   <NA>   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>  
#3 TAP1   <NA>   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>  
#4 <NA>   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>   TAP3
```

Comment: This doesn't add a new column for TAP3, very impressive though, I'm trying to get my head around the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution. This goes through all possible factors in your column (i.e., `TAP1`, `TAP2`) and checks whereabouts they're present. For places where they are present, it returns the name of the level. For places where they're absent, it returns `NA`. Then, I repackage the resulting list into a data frame and rename the columns.

```r
# Original data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "TAP1", "TAP1", "TAP2"))

# Repackage
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(levels(df$x), function(x)ifelse(df$x == x, x, NA)))

# Fix names
names(df2) <- levels(df$x)

# Check results
df2
#>   TAP1 TAP2
#> 1 <NA> <NA>
#> 2 TAP1 <NA>
#> 3 TAP1 <NA>
#> 4 <NA> TAP2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

In light of your update:

```r
# Original data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "TAP1", "TAP1", "TAP2"), 
                 y = c("TAP1", "TAP2",   "TAP2", "TAP3" ))

# Define splitter function
splitter <- function(foo){
  tmp <- data.frame(lapply(levels(foo), function(x)ifelse(foo == x, x, NA)))
  names(tmp) <- levels(foo)
  tmp
}

# Run over data frame and bind together
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, splitter))
#>   x.TAP1 x.TAP2 y.TAP1 y.TAP2 y.TAP3
#> 1   <NA>   <NA>   TAP1   <NA>   <NA>
#> 2   TAP1   <NA>   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>
#> 3   TAP1   <NA>   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>
#> 4   <NA>   TAP2   <NA>   <NA>   TAP3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Same rationale as before, but I define a function that is applied to each column and the results are bound together using `do.call` and `cbind`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `tidyverse` and the `dummies` package. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dummies)

df2 <- dummy.data.frame(df) %>% select(-ends_with("NA"))

cols <- str_remove(names(df2), regex("^x|^y"))

df3 <- modify2(df2, cols, ~ifelse(.x == 0, NA, .y))

df3
#   xTAP1 xTAP2 yTAP1 yTAP2 yTAP3
# 1  <NA>  <NA>  TAP1  <NA>  <NA>
# 2  TAP1  <NA>  <NA>  TAP2  <NA>
# 3  TAP1  <NA>  <NA>  TAP2  <NA>
# 4  <NA>  TAP2  <NA>  <NA>  TAP3
```

Comment: Nice option with dummies